# Plugin for editing options on multisite?

Tags: multisite, plugins, options

does anyone know of a plugin for mass editing of settings on a multisite installation? Something like Plugin Commander for Settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is what you looking for:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/yd-wpmu-sitewide-options/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this really answers your question, but have you looked at **[CheezCAP](http://code.google.com/p/cheezcap/)**?

It's a framework to allow a theme to register options and settings panels on the fly, so that on a multi-site install you can more easily add options to the themes across the board, and manage the settings on a site-by-site basis.

Doesn't quite do what you're looking for, though...